# Convert a for loop to concat String into a lambda expression

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following for loop which iterates through a list of strings and stores the first character of each word in a `StringBuilder`.  I would like to know how can I transform this to a lambda expression

```
StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();
for (String l : list) {
    chars.append(l.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assuming you call `toString()` on the `StringBuilder` afterwards, I think you're just looking for [`Collectors.joining()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--), after mapping each string to a single-character substring:

```
String result = list
    .stream()
    .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        list.add("baz");
        String result = list
            .stream()
            .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(result); // fbb
    }
}
```

Note the use of `substring` instead of `charAt`, so we still have a stream of strings to work with.

Answer (score 22):

Tons of ways to do this - the **most simple option**: stick to adding to a `StringBuilder` and do this:

```
StringBuilder chars = new StringBuilder();

list.forEach(l -> chars.append(l.charAt(0)));
```

Comment: then you can use just `list.forEach(…)` without `.stream()`

Answer (score 14):

Without creating many intermediate String objects you can do it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = list.stream()
                       .mapToInt(l -> l.codePointAt(0))
                       .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                                StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
                                StringBuilder::append);
```

Note that using `codePointAt` is much better than `charAt` as if your string starts with surrogate pair, using `charAt` you may have an unpredictable result.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three different solutions to this problem.  Each solution filters empty strings first as otherwise `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` may be thrown.

This solution is the same as the solution from Tagir with the added code for filtering empty strings.  I included it here primarily to compare to the other two solutions I have provided.

```
List<String> list =
    Arrays.asList("the", "", "quick", "", "brown", "", "fox");
StringBuilder builder = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .mapToInt(s -> s.codePointAt(0))
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
String result = builder.toString();
Assert.assertEquals("tqbf", result);
```

The second solution uses [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), and leverages a relatively new container type called [`CodePointAdapter`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/string/immutable/CodePointAdapter.html) that was added in version 7.0.

```
MutableList<String> list =
    Lists.mutable.with("the", "", "quick", "", "brown", "", "fox");
LazyIntIterable iterable = list.asLazy()
    .reject(String::isEmpty)
    .collectInt(s -> s.codePointAt(0));
String result = CodePointAdapter.from(iterable).toString();
Assert.assertEquals("tqbf", result);
```

The third solution uses Eclipse Collections again, but with [`injectInto`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/IntIterable.html#injectInto-T-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.primitive.ObjectIntToObjectFunction-) and `StringBuilder` instead of `CodePointAdapter`.

```
MutableList<String> list =
    Lists.mutable.with("the", "", "quick", "", "brown", "", "fox");
StringBuilder builder = list.asLazy()
    .reject(String::isEmpty)
    .collectInt(s -> s.codePointAt(0))
    .injectInto(new StringBuilder(), StringBuilder::appendCodePoint);
String result = builder.toString();
Assert.assertEquals("tqbf", result);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way using method reference :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ABC", "CDE");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

list.forEach(sb::append);

String concatString = sb.toString();
```